# Sandbox violation while accessing image files in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, sandbox

I'm working on an image gallery application. Very frequently I'm getting Sandbox violation Error like `Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.`. Some times its raising by cleaning the project. Every time I'm using my application's backup and updating and then the error is raising. Though I'm accessing local image files, getting error. I'm using try-catch to catch the location but no use. How to get rid of this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About loading local images. You should check and fix Flash Player trust file for your SWF as described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_25.html). Flash Builder done it automatically but who knows…

About problem with loading images in web it can be problem related to loading images from other domain which hasn't proper `crossdomain.xml` file. If so you should use some kind of proxy on your server.

If you're loading files from your own domain maybe [this deployment checklist](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deployingoverview_05.html#178289) can help you. Also you can use some debugging proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see the real queries and responses.

Comment: Hi @Constantiner, you are right. I did not change those settings but I change browser from Firefox to Chrome. Now its not raising any error. As your guess, its the problem of settings. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

If u Clean the project It Will remove all your 
assets files in the bin-debug folder and it will be 
recreated during the Build.Some times the build wont
creates the file properly i think that time you are 
getting the error.

At most avoid cleaning.It may also happens by the 
out dated flash player version.

It may also happens by the following ways,

- incorrect path to the upload file script - check relative and absolute paths
- a incorrect location for the files to be stored on the server specified inside server-side upload script - check path is correct and permissions are correct
- file is too large so server rejects it - check max file size
- there is no space on the server to save the file - check server hard drive space
- your actionscript handler is going out of scope because it's declared locally,
  etc - create a strong event listener or declare the file reference on the class

Check one of the option and Comment is must.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation about the causes @Sudharsanan, I think some file's path might be raising the error. I will take care of these scenarios.